# Jquery does not work on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to run jquery code when i click on a button.

This is my jquery code:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" >   
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchtextbtn').click(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
</script>
```

And my html looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="content_inner">
    <div class ="page_header">
          <h2>Location Master</h2>
        <div id="search">
            <table  width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                         <font color="#AFBECF">@Html.Label("Search")</font>
                    </td>
                    <td>  

                       <input  id="searchtextbtn" type="submit" value="search">
                <input  id="searchtextbtn" type="button" value="search"> @*not woring*@

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div></div></div>
```

But here when i click on the button nothing happens.

This is the page once I run my project:

[image]

When I click on the "Location Master" link, partial view will be displayed like this:

[image]

which contain search button.

Comment: Please change button type to `button` then `submit`

Comment: Have you included jQuery file?

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/3oz9myf4/, make sure you have jQuery included

Comment: Check your browser console to see if there are any errors

Comment: Your code is working, may be jQuery library be the reason, or css

Comment: Does the page refresh on click or does it just not work?

Comment: Change `<script type ="text/javascript" >` to `<script type="text/javascript" >  ` OR `<script>`

Comment: Have you included jQuery twice?  then remove duplicate include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CDN to your code

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```